# A basic question on rational and irrational number

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we take all the rationals and take any neighbourhood around each of them. Will they cover whole $\Bbb R$. I think so as rationals are dense. So, for each irrational we can find a rational which is arbitrary close to it. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: the density implies that if you consider all the rationals, no matter what the scale at which you are looking $\mathbb{R}$ at, there will be no "holes"

Comment: They won't necessarily cover. Consider $(-\infty,\pi)$, and $(\pi,\infty)$.

Comment: @TomCollinge The OP wanted nhoods about the rationals.

Comment: @David Mitra. Thanks, I missread that part.

Comment: @David Mitra: Does the same argument apply to the irrationals taking $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, +\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

No to the first statement, yes to the second.

As you probably know, there are only countably many rationals, so we can enumerate them in some order $q_1$, $q_2$, etc. Now let us look at the set:

$$U := \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} B(q_i, 2^{-i-1})$$

where $B(q,r)$ is the open ball with center $q$ and radius $r$. This set has measure $\leq 0.5$ (which you can see by summing up all the radii), is open and contains all rational numbers.

So despite the fact that the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there are very small open neighborhoods of all the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about arbitrarily close constant neighbourhood then yes.

However, it might be of interest, that if you allow certain restrictions this is not always true. Look at the [Roth Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem) (Fields Medal) which states that there are finitely many rationals $\frac pq$ such that :
$$|\alpha - \frac pq| < \frac{c}{q^{2+\epsilon}}$$
where $\alpha$ is an algebraic irrational, $\epsilon  > 0$ and $c$ is any constant. Taking $c$ to be small enough, the "finitely many" becomes "no rational".